# 5-digit square has sum not 29.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Show that there is no  five-digit number is a square number . where the sum of his digit is 29 ,

I tried to solve this question more and more , But , I didn't get any solution .

I hope I can understand it well here.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: See http://burningmath.blogspot.ca/2013/09/how-to-check-if-number-is-perfect-square.html

Comment: Usually the title should summarize what you are asking. In this case, I recommend a title "5-digit square has sum not 29." Your title is longer and is not informative. Also, why the exclamation marks !! ?

Comment: I edit the title . Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Make use of the following facts:

- The remainder when the number $n$ is divided by $3$ is same when the remainder when the sum of digits of $n$ is divided by $3$.
- Any square number is either $0 \pmod 3$ or $1\pmod3$.

Comment: I didn't know this facts . now the question is very easy.